# como acceder a un campo especifico en una variable stdclass object

Tags: php, laravel

tengo esta session de donde obtengo unos datos:

```
$data = Session::get('fails');
$data_parse = json_decode($data,true);
```

y obtengo este "arreglo de array":

```
ARRAY ( 
      [ERROR] => ARRAY ( [0] => LA CHOZA DEL DUENDE ) 
      [FAILS] => ARRAY ( [0] => 27 APRIL 2021 - 09:00 AM - 09:30 AM ) 
)
```

intento acceder con `$data_parse['ERROR'][0];` pero me dice que no existe

cuando hago `var_dump` me da esto:

```
ARRAY(2) { ["ERROR"]=> ARRAY(1) { [0]=> STRING(19) "LA CHOZA DEL DUENDE" } ["FAILS"]=> ARRAY(1) { [0]=> STRING(31) "27 APRIL 2021 09:00 AM 09:30 AM" } }
```

Comment: Exactamente ¿cual es el mensaje de error y como estas imprimiendo `$data_parse` para obtener ese resultado?

Comment: Revisa la respuesta. Si no funciona, agrega el resultado de `var_dump($data_parse);` a la pregunta pulsando en [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Si el array tiene la estructura que dices:

```
$data_parse=
    array(
      "ERROR" => array ('LA CHOZA DEL DUENDE'),
      'FAILS' => array ('27 APRIL 2021 - 09:00 AM - 09:30 AM')
    );
```

Entonces puedes leer lo que hay en `ERROR` de este modo:

```
echo $data_parse['ERROR'][0];
```

**Salida:**

```
LA CHOZA DEL DUENDE
```

Debes tener en cuenta que:

1. Las claves de array son *case sensitive*, significa que si lo buscas como `Error` o `error` o `ErrOr` no lo encontrarás. La clave es  `ERROR` todo en mayúscula.
2. Dentro de `ERROR` hay otro array (en este caso con un sólo elemento), por esto accedimos a él usando el índice `0`. Si hubiera más valores y los necesitarás todos tendrás que hacerlo por medio de un bucle, con `implode` o del modo que mejor te resulte.

Comment: al utilizar echo $data_parse['ERROR'][0]; me bota este error: Undefined index: ERROR y al hacer var_dump me dale esto: ARRAY(2) { ["ERROR"]=> ARRAY(1) { [0]=> STRING(19) "LA CHOZA DEL DUENDE" } ["FAILS"]=> ARRAY(1) { [0]=> STRING(31) "27 APRIL 2021 09:00 AM 09:30 AM" } }

Comment: @FernandoAbelGonzalesCh el `var_dump` que refieres es exactamente la salida que daría un error como el `$data_parse` que he puesto a modo de ejemplo en mi respuesta, en el cual esto `echo $data_parse['ERROR'][0];` no debería dar ningún error. Me gustaría ver qué arroja un `var_dump($data);`, pues si te sale *Undefined index* significa que el problema está en otro lado o puede que en contexto determinado los datos sean otros. No puede ser que el `var_dump` arroje lo que dices y que luego te de *Undefined index*.

Comment: esto es de $data: 
OBJECT(ILLUMINATE\SUPPORT\VIEWERRORBAG)#1661 (1) { ["BAGS":PROTECTED]=> ARRAY(1) { ["DEFAULT"]=> OBJECT(ILLUMINATE\SUPPORT\MESSAGEBAG)#1662 (2) { ["MESSAGES":PROTECTED]=> ARRAY(2) { ["ERROR"]=> ARRAY(1) { [0]=> STRING(19) "LA CHOZA DEL DUENDE" } ["FAILS"]=> ARRAY(1) { [0]=> STRING(31) "27 APRIL 2021 09:00 AM 09:30 AM" } } ["FORMAT":PROTECTED]=> STRING(8) ":MESSAGE" } } }